# Using Ascoli-Arzela theorem to prove a set is compact

Tags: real-analysis, arzela-ascoli

Let $D= \{f_k(x) = \sin kx/(1+k);\quad k= 0,1,2,\dots\quad x \in [0,1]\}$.  Show that $D$ is compact.

I know that I should approach this kind of question by Ascoli-Arzela theorem (proving $D$ is equicontinuous, bounded and closed). For equicontinuity, do we always use $3\epsilon$ technique? Thus, first find the limit $f$ (I am not sure about $f$ is $0$.) And I am confused about proving that it is closed.
In general, I don't know how to handle this question which contains specific functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually proceed directly: let $f_k$ be a sequence in $D$, then argue that either it has infinitely many copies of the same element of $D$, or else it converges to $0$.

Arzela-Ascoli would basically require the same argumentation in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Note that each $f_k$ is 1-lipschitz. In particular, this implies that, for each $\varepsilon > 0$, you can write $(|x-y| < \varepsilon) \Rightarrow (|f_k(x)-f_k(y)| < \varepsilon)$ for each $ k \ge 1$, therefore the family is equicontinuous.

Comment: yes but how do you should bounded and closed?

Comment: Well the boundedness is quite easy to see (each function has sup norm smaller than 1) and the closedness follows from the fact that 0 is the only limit point of D (again, by considering the norms of the elements, you see that, aside from 0, they are all isolated) and is already in D.

Comment: So in general, a sequence of function is closed if it contains the pointwise limit of the sequence am I right? What is the pointwise limit of the sequence is discontinuous?

Comment: Well no, it is closed if it contains the pointwise limit *and* if it converges uniformly to that limit (which implies that the limit is continuous).

Answer (score 0):

Note that with $k=0$ this sequence contains its own limit. This is the second most trivial situation for a compact set, the most trivial being a set of finitely many points.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, since each of the $f_k$'s are Lipschitz, then they are equicontinuous, they are of course also uniformly bounded since $||f_k||_\infty$ $<1$. This is enough to conclude that $D$ is compact. You do not need to prove closure because compact subsets of a Hausdorff space (all metric spaces, including function spaces), are always closed.